# Need help in Oracle OS Authentication

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am trying to use oracle os authentication using jdbc.

I have solaris sparc 32 bit machine and oracle 10g.
I have alredy setup os authentication in backend and user is ops$oracle.
I am using following code to connect to db using os authentication.

```
String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=<host>)"
            + "(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=db1)))";

        //String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@<host>:1521:db1";
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.setProperty(              OracleConnection.CONNECTION_PROPERTY_THIN_VSESSION_OSUSER,              
                "oracle");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);
```

But when i run this code then i get following error ::

```
    java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:440)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:389)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:382)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.processError(T4CTTIfun.java:573)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.processError(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:431)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:445)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:191)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:366)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:752)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:366)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:536)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:228)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:521)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at OracleOSAuth.main(OracleOSAuth.java:32)
```

Please help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: I tried both the urls but same error is coming.

Comment: you need to add oracle jar files into this project. This jar files is available in oracle installation path.

Comment: Yes...I have already added jar files ojdbc6.jar and ojdbc5.jar files to the path. Actually i tried with both the jars.

Comment: i think your username and password is mismatch.. check it again..

Comment: but for os authentication password is not required. Oracle services are running. in backend using "sqlplus /"  I am able to connect to db.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@dbaprod1:1544:SHR1_PRD", username, passwd);
Statement stmt = con.createStatement() ; 
PreparedStatement prepareUpdatePrice = con.prepareStatement( "select * from table");
```

Comment: But for Oracle OS authentication, password is not required. check this link :: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/java.112/e16548/clntsec.htm#CIHCBCBC